# Ionic build in Azure pipeline

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, permissions, azure-pipelines, windows-server

I have a build server running the latest version of Visual Studio build agent (as of May 2020) in order to build (CI/CD) my Ionic Android app. I installed Ionic by doing (from Administrator account):

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

Then I want to build the apk by doing

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

However, the build agent runs as NETWORK SERVICE and can in turn not find "ionic" program and therefore fails to build. The ionic program seems to be located in my Administrator's AppData. How can I install the necessary toolchain so it can be accessed/run by the Visual Studio agent? Same goes for the jarsigner and zipalign program (these however should be in Program Files so I guess these will be no problem to find for the NETWORK SERVICE).

I thought supplying the -g parameter would install it globally somehow but Ionic still resides in my users AppData. I have tried running it both elevated and not elevated. I am running on Windows Server 2019. Logging in to the server with my Administrator account and run the build command above from that account works fine.